# How to detect words in a sentence without white-spaces in Java?

Tags: java, nlp

Supposing that I've the following strings:

- `"myteststringwithoutanyspace"`
- `"myOtherSTRINGwithoutanyspace"`

How would you separate the words inside it in Java?

My current strategy is focused using SimpleNLG. But in fact, I didn't find any docs about using SimpleNLG to separate strings into words.

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words)

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665501/word-splitting-statistical-approach/9688034#9688034) might also be relevant

Answer (score 0):

Well, your solution will almost never be perfect.

I would approach it by getting an English dictionary file, sort by length, then sort by amount of use, and then match it in the string, as I see it, that would be the only option.